# Copy text file content into a 2D Array in C

Tags: c

I want to copy the content of a file that has a 10 by 10 array of characters to a 2D array. I verified but the compiler gives me an empty screen. The file is opening since the program dosen't print: "error in opening file", i would appreciate it if you help me. This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
   char puzzle[10][10], line[10];
   int i,j, rows=0;
   FILE *fp;
   fp=fopen("arr.txt", "r");
   if (fp== NULL) { 
      printf("Error in opening file\n");
      return 1;
   }

   while(!EOF)
   {
      if(fgets(line, 10, fp) != NULL){
         for(i=0; i<(strlen(line)-1); i++)
            puzzle[rows][i] = line[i];
      }
      rows++;   
   }
   for(i=0; i<10; i++)
      for(j=0; j<10; j++)
         printf("%c", puzzle[i][j]);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: It is easier to copy strings using `strcpy`. BTW, you forgot to `fclose` the file.

Answer (score 1):

You reading-loop condition will *always* be false, so you never read anything. This will led to *undefined behavior* when you print out the uninitialized `puzzle` matrix.

The macro `EOF` is defined as `-1`, and in C anything non-zero is true, and since you negate this "true" value through the `!` operator your condition will be false.

The usual newbie way to do it is using

```
while (!feof(fp)) { ... }
```

[but that's the wrong solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) (in most cases).

Instead do

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) { ... }
```

---

By the way, you might *still* have *undefined behavior* if the line you read is less than 9 characters, as not all of the `puzzle` matrix will be initialized. You might want to initialize it first, which can be done when you define it:

```
char puzzle[10][10] = { 0 };
```

Also note that if the lines you read are exactly 9 characters or longer, then the `fgets` call will not include the newline in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong size for the arrays.

When a line has 10 characters, you need to have

```
// 10 characters, the newline and the terminating null character.
char line[12];
char puzzle[10][12];
```